# Unit Testing Controllers with http request

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In C#, I do have a method in my controller which gets content from request object.

```
public class xController: BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("confirm")]
    public void Confirmation(string Content)
    {
        var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

}
```

I build a unit test with following code but getting **error with null ref** for request object.

```
[Test]
public void Confirmation()
{
   //arrange
   var con = new xController();

   //act
   var res = con.Confirmation("hello");

   //assert
   Assert.IsNotNull(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [TestHelper](https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) from [MVCContrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcContrib.Mvc5/), you should be able to write something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Confirmation()
{
    //arrange
    TestControllerBuilder builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
    var con = new xController();
    builder.InitializeController(con);

    //act
    var res = con.Confirmation("hello");

    //assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1) Inject a HttpContextBase in your controller and use it to access any of its properties, e.g. 'Request'.

2) Mock and set the ControllerContext in your test.

Something around these lines:

```
    [Test]
    public void Confirmation()
    {
        //arrange
        var mock = new Mock<HttpControllerContext>();
        mock.SetupGet(p => p.Request.Content).Returns(theObjectToBeReturned);
        var con = new xController();
        con.ControllerContext = mock.Object;

        //act
        var res = con.Confirmation("hello");

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(res);
    }
```

Comment: Also did a ninja edit to the sample as I realised this is a WebAPI controller.

Comment: is mock and fixture same thing??? in same project m having sample with fixture<x>.build().createmany...

Comment: They can work together. AutoFixture is a library that generates test data. Haven't tried it but potentially you could create a controller context object and set it in the controller.